# Django-filter, how to make multiple fields search? (with django-filter!)

Tags: python, django, django-filter

How can I make multiple fields search with Django-filter from model like:

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    loc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    loc_mansioned = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    loc_country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    loc_modern = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

I need one input field on my website, that can search over all fields of Location model

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can probably create a custom filter and do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
import django_filters


class LocationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method='my_custom_filter', label="Search")

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['q']

    def my_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(loc__icontains=value) |
            Q(loc_mansioned__icontains=value) | 
            Q(loc_country__icontains=value) | 
            Q(loc_modern__icontains=value)
        )
```

This would filter by any of of those fields. You can replace the `icontains` with whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! It works!
Where should I place `icontains`?

Comment: @Medevin: Instead of *field lookup* [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#icontains), you could use `contains`, `startswith`, `equals` and many more. Follow link to see other field lookups.

Comment: Actually this answer has a flaw in it.  It does `Location.objects` instead of queryset in the return statement.

Comment: What you are specifying the model in the Meta class? Would this still work without the Meta class? My understanding is that Meta class in django-filters are to use fields from the specified model but in this case, `q` is a new field not present in the `Location` model

Answer (score 3):

This is perfect. I'm trying to do a dynamic filter, with a switch to get one more field in the search if checked. Something like this:

```
def my_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    return Reference.objects.filter(
        Q(ref_title__icontains=value))

def my_custom_filter_with_description(self, queryset, name, value):
    return Reference.objects.filter(
        Q(ref_title__icontains=value) | Q(complete_description__icontains=value))
```

But I have no clue how to link the switch to the class

Comment: You are using ModelName.objects.filter but why didn't you use queryset param. In my case I'm  getting queryset param empty.

Answer (score 2):

Due that you've defined Location as an object, to filter by multiple fields just use the `filter` method.

```
filterlocation = Location.objects.filter(loc=formloc, loc_mansioned=formlocmansioned, loc_country=formloccountry, loc_modern=formlocmodern)
```

But you need to implement a better way to use this filters, so only the result that have all conditions will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, since the other one was not working directly:

```
@staticmethod
def filter_stock(qs, name, value):
    return qs.filter(
        Q(ticker__exact=value) | Q(company__iexact=value)
    )
```

Comment: In a scenario where you search by typing you MUST avoid using ```__exact``` and use ```contains``` or ```icontains``` lookups instead